# Mongoose aggregate, can't dynamically add someField: { $not; null }

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am generating a query based on user's input as to conditions.  User can set custom filtering by making selections.

All is okay, so far.  For example, this works:

```
exports.getJoinedTransactions = function(firmId, page, pageSize, billerId, matterId, words, billingStatus, cb) {

    let firmIdToObjId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(global.user.firmId);
    let query = { firmId: firmIdToObjId };

    if ( typeof billerId === "object" ) {
        billerId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(billerId);
        query.contactId = billerId;
    }

    if ( typeof matterId === "object" ) {
        matterId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(matterId);
        query.matterId = matterId;
    }

    ....

    myAggregate = [
        { $sort: { date: -1 } },
        {
            $match: query
        },

    ....

    Transactions.aggregate(myAggregate).exec( function(err, transactions) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        someVar = transactions.length;

    ....
```

This builds the query nicely and runs well.  Now, however, I have a slightly different requirement to add to the list.  I want to also include a possible query for null or not null.  Something like this:

```
if (typeof billingStatus === "string" && billingStatus != "") {

    if (billingStatus === "billed") {
        query.billId = { $not: null } ;          <-- This does not work.
    } else if (billingStatus === "unbilled") {
        query.billId = null;                     <-- This works!
    }
}
```

When I run this code setting the status to "billed," no error is thrown.  However, no "transactions" are returned, either.  An error is thrown:  "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined."

How can I fix the broken part?

Edit:  By the way, there are 5 records total, and 1 is billed.  When it works, I should receive the 1 record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a special [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/index.html) operator which allows you to check property type. So if you have explicit nulls in your collection, they will be of type `10`. Full list of type codes [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/). So to check if a property is not equal to `null` you can use following query.

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            billId: {  $not: { $type: 10 } }  
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Smart!  Thank you!