# MongoDB / Mongoose: aggregate - need to query on date range

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a similar issue to a previous one I had:  [Mongoose aggregate, can't dynamically add someField: { $not; null }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085435/mongoose-aggregate-cant-dynamically-add-somefield-not-null)

I am trying to perform a query on a date range.

This is my attempted syntax, which is wrong (and throws same kind of error as stated in the previous issue):

```
if (typeof dateBeginning === "string" && dateBeginning != "" && typeof 
dateEnding === "string" && dateEnding != "") {

    query.date = { $and: [ { $gte: new Date(dateBeginning) }, { $lte: new Date(dateEnding) } ] };

}
```

Comment: Try  `query.date =  { $gte: new Date(dateBeginning),  $lte: new Date(dateEnding) } ;` or with $and( not needed) you can try `query = { $and: [ { date:{ $gte: new Date(dateBeginning) } }, { date: { $lte: new Date(dateEnding) } } ] }`

Comment: Thanks, @Veeram!  If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it.